# iPhone Location Services - app not showing

Tags: ios, service, location

Our app uses location services, and registers in the normal way. We have an issue on 1 (!) iPhone where it's not showing in the Location Services, no matter what we do. The question is, does anyone know if this is a bug in iOS, or could there be something we're not doing?

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: If it's an issue with just one device, you should specify exactly what's different about that device (version number, model number, etc.). It's also possible that the device is broken (especially if an identical device has no issues).

Comment: Try using a different app on that iPhone that uses location services as well,  does it work with that? Have you tried resetting that iPhone?

Comment: Other (already installed - haven't tried new apps yet) apps are in the Location Services settings. I'll try installing a different app & see what happens with that.

Comment: @SomaMan what happened? were u able to solve? I am stuck with this too

Answer (score 0):

The app needs to trigger location settings to appear open up Facebook on ur phone click on the top left corner then press on nearby and allow it once that is done Facebook will appear under location settings

Answer (score 0):

The best way to trigger facebook location services is to go to settings in your facebook app, next go to events. In events you will find a setting icon you need to click that. it will popup location permissions. Select while using.

If you can't find the setting icon in events tab, try to create a new event and it will ask you for location.